# socket.io push data whenever database is updated

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I'm writing a websocket application which should push data to my php file whenever a database entry changes. Right now, as a very basic start, I've set an interval Timer, and push every 20 seconds to the client, wheter there was a change or not (the fields are just for playing around -- password...):

SERVERSIDE:

```
setInterval(pushData, 20000);

function pushData() {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM testtable WHERE username="michael"', function(err,rows,fields) {
       if (err) throw err;
        io.emit('newdata', rows[0].password);

    });
}
```

CLIENT PHP SCRIPT:

```
socket.on('newdata', function(msg) {
    var data = document.getElementById('dataentries');
    data.innerHTML = msg;
    });
```

What would be a best practice approach to query and update only if a DB entry has changed? Can I set a trigger from mysql to node.js?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest thing and also legit way to do it, would be to query the data first, check if they have changed, then do the change and send message to the client. If it did not change, don't do the update.

Comment: This is what I thought about, too. But I still had to query the DB every 20 seconds or so. Isn't there a way to get rid of the many queries? I have to query a DB with 20.000 entries when it comes to production.

Comment: add some good indexes, then 20k lines is not an issue. With good indexes you can query millions of lines in no time. check mysql docs for how to add indexes to columns. Basically it's just a help for mysql to sort the table, so it can faster retrieve the rows you search for.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use an `ORM` in your server application - I would put the broadcasting logic into a `POST_SAVE` hook.

In case you don't own the application, but have access to the database configuration - here is the trick.

1. Enable logging of queries (consider the possible performance downgrade, so probably I would configure it on a replica instance)
2. In your script - watch the log file for changes, probably parse it on change to check which table was updated etc.
3. Based on the logic above - broadcast events